# Type safety with JCombobox on Java 7

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, java-7

I cant get rid of one new typesafety warning in java7.

I have the following JCombobox object defined

```
private JComboBox<Integer> combobox_current_year;
```

And the the constructor

```
combobox_current_year = new JComboBox(options.getList_years().toArray());
```

Java 7 gives me now the following warning:

> Type safety: The expression of type JComboBox needs unchecked
>   conversion to conform to JComboBox

After changing the code to

```
combobox_current_year = new JComboBox<Integer>((Integer[]) options.getList_years().toArray());
```

I get the following exception:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; 
>   cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Integer;    at
>   jamm.gui.FinanzmanagerGui.mainWindow(FinanzmanagerGui.java:123)   at
>   jamm.StartJamm$1.run(StartJamm.java:43)   at
>   java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:705)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:101)   at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:666)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:664)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:675)   at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the `toArray()` method returns an object of type `Object[]` which is a totally different type to `Integer[]` (so making the cast fail). You have to pass in a differently-typed array to `toArray(…)` to resolve that. The most efficient method of getting an array out of a list is this:

```
List<Integer> tmp = options.getList_years();
combobox_current_year = new JComboBox<Integer>(
        tmp.toArray(new Integer[tmp.size()]));
```

I use a temporary variable to hold the list because I want to pre-size the array so that the values can be just copied into it. Passing in a shorter array (e.g., of length 0) would also work, but would cause an extra allocation to happen. (You could make it work by keeping the length-zero array in a `private static` field; it's effectively immutable so you can share it with no ill-consequences. But I prefer to pre-size as that leaves less clutter at the class level.)

Comment: You don't need to specify the size of the list when using toArray. Using tmp.toArray(new Integer[0]) is sufficient, as the passed in parameter is *only* used to derive the correct type information of the return value.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel no if the array is of sufficient length (`>= size()`) the collection will fill it

Comment: @ratchetfreak I did not know that. I still think it is simpler to create the 0-sized array, because then you don't need to query the size yourself :)

Comment: @Mark: I do that sometimes, but this method is faster if you're not keeping that zero-length array around. Difference is pretty minimal.

Answer (score 5):

try doing

```
combobox_current_year = new JComboBox<Integer>(options.getList_years().toArray(new Integer[0]));
```

toArray of the collection framework always returns a Object[] if you want a specific array type you need to supply one

Answer (score 2):

I guess that means that `options.getList_years()` returns a `List<?>`.

This means you need to convert from an Object[] to an Integer[], which has to be done with a copy operation.

```
Object[] years = options.getList_years().toArray();
new JComboBox(Arrays.copyOf(years, years.length, Integer.class));
```